# Progress bar for a bash script running from php

Tags: php, bash, progress-bar

With unvaluable help from people on StackOverflow I managed to run a bash script from php. Now everything is running fine but as the script takes some minutes to end I would like to see progress. In the bash script there are some printf commands that output error/success messages.

As a newbie in php I assumed those messages would appear as they are executed in the bash script. But I don't get any output although the script is finished. I can see the files created and for sure the script finished but I can't see any output from php in the browser.

How can I check the progress when the script is still running? Why php does not seem to end?

Following is the php script.

```
<?php

echo "<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC -//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd>
      <html xmlns=http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml>
      <head>
      <meta http-equiv=Content-Type content=text/html; charset=UTF-8 />
      <title>Title</title>
      <link href=../style.css rel=stylesheet type=text/css>
      </head>
      <body topmargin=0 leftmargin=0>";
echo '<font color=blue>';

echo '------------------------------------------------------------- <br>';
echo 'Inicio de la generación manual de mapas de olas de calor<br>';
echo 'Este proceso tarda varios minutos<br>';
echo '-------------------------------------------------------------<br>';
echo date('h:i:s') . "\n";
$output = shell_exec('/home/meteo/www/RAMS/olas/generar-mapas.bash');
echo "<pre>".$output."</pre>";
echo '</font>';
echo '</body>';
echo '</html>';

?>
```

I've read some posts in the forum about php, Ajax and jQuery for progress bars but I just know some very basic php. Is there a simple solution for a novice in php?
Thanks for your help

Comment: Pro PHP Tip: don't feel the need to `echo` absolutely everything. You can simply close the `?>`, output HTML, then reopen the `<?php` when you need to. Pro HTML Tip: the `<font>` tag is _very_ old-fashioned and should no longer be used. If you want the font to be blue, use CSS.

Comment: @tom-fenech Agree with the use of CSS, just a copy-paste mistake. Don't need to echo everything but the point is that any single `echo` appears. Sorry if too basic but  what does close `?>` means? Is it not closed? the html output does not appear. Thanks for answering.

Comment: I thought of a solution by sending the output of the bash script to an autorefreshing html open in an iframe. But it seems a tricky workaround, there should be a nice clean php way to do it.

Comment: This is general advice, separate to your issue, which is why I only posted it as a comment. You can open and close PHP tags in the middle of your script, so you don't need to write all of your HTML in a PHP string. Hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`shell_exec()` blocks till the child process finishes, use `popen()` instead:

```
$p = popen('/home/meteo/www/RAMS/olas/generar-mapas.bash', 'r');
while(!feof($p)) {
    echo fgets($p);
    ob_flush();
    flush();
}
pclose($p);
```

Comment: Hi @marek and thanks. It seems popen does not work for me. It does not start any process, bash script does not run.

Comment: I forgot to add mode, I hope that helps. It might be neccessary to output more bytes, in case there's implicit buffer somewhere.

Comment: Just needed to add  `2>&1','r'` to `popen` on your answer